# Joomla frontend publishing options not shown correctly

Tags: joomla, frontend

I am creating a Joomla template with the use of Bootstrap.

When editing at the frontend, some options are not shown correctly.

For example: the options under 'Categorie'.
[image: Options in the publishing tab]

<strike>url: https://test.wouterschaeffer.nl/ 

Login using name: test password: user 

Edit page (arrow down menu) and go to publishing</strike>

I am not able to find a solution, hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Its difficult to guess from this data alone. You need to provide your url as it can be css or js or your coding issues. Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following rows to your CSS:

```
.chzn-container {
   width: 100%!important;
}
```

or with fixed width:

```
.chzn-container {
   width: 200px!important;
}
```